# warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size 64bit

Tags: c++, gnu

I've got a piece of code that works well on 32bit but on a 64bit system i get a warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size

Here is the code

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
void *SSLv3_client_method(void) {
return (void *) SSLv23_client_method();
}
```

This on a Debian x64 system on which i am getting the error

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are these OpenSSL functions or just stuff you are making up yourself?  In either case you need to use prototypes properly instead of casts.

Comment: please, show the complete list of header files you have included so far, as as such, the functions are incompletely defined.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using the [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_new.html) library.

Add

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
```

to the source file.

Comment: `SSLv23_client_method` returns `const SSL_METHOD *`. The correct fix is probably for OP to include the right prototype (preferably by including the right header, instead of ad-hoc prototypes as he seems to be doing)

Comment: :3: error: conflicting types for â€˜SSLv3_client_methodâ€™
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:2029: note: previous declaration of â€˜SSLv3_client_methodâ€™ was here   <-- Does not appear to work